# orbital angular momentum of the silver atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In a silver atom, the first 46 electrons are all paired and according to David McIntyre in Quantum Mechanics,

> **The electrons in the closed shells can be represented by a spherically symmetric cloud with no orbital or spin angular momentum.**

How do we show that the total orbital angular momentum for a spherically symmetric distribution is zero - using geometry?

furthermore, does this configuration of angular momentum - orbital angular momentum - change if the atoms are subject to an inhomogeneous magnetic field, like in the Stern Gerlach experiment? If not then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full shell, the addition of the expectation values of any angular momentum $L_i$ is zero, and similarly for the spin operators $\sigma_i$. This is not hard to see - for $l(l+1)$ as the expectation value of $L^2$ for a s,p,d,f subshell, the basis of that subshell is spanned by states indexed by integers between $-l$ and $l$, and since that l is also the actual value for the angular momentum in a given direction, full occupancy of these states implies vanishing total angular momentum. Even easier for spin - there are only up and down states, and equally many of them in every shell, so if they're all occupied, the net spin is zero.

Comment: could you elaborate what you mean by the addition of expectation values - is this quantum mechanical addition of probabilities? that doesn't mean that <psi|psi> = 0, yes?

Comment: @ApprenticeHacker: There are $2l+1$ states in every subshell of constant $l$. If you evaluate an angular momentum operator upon one of them, the result is just the value between $-l$ and $l$ that labels the state. Now, given two electrons, two of these states are realized, and the total angular momentum is just the sum of their labels (because the label $m_l \in \{-l,\dots,l\}$ is defined as the eigenvalue of one of the $L_i$). Given a full subshell, the total angular momentum is just the sum of all labels, which is zero.

Comment: This is not QM addition of probabilities, it is realizing that for two systems $H_1,H_2$ the total angular momentum upon the combined space $H_1 \otimes H_2$ is given by $L \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes L$, but I got the impression that I should not use the tensor space formalism to answer your question, so I tried to formulate it in natural language.

Comment: Even though this answer have been accepted, be aware that there are a lot of handwaving arguments here. "If you evaluate an angular momentum operator upon one of them, the result is just the value between $-\ell$ and $\ell$ that labels the state." @ACuriusMind is probably talking about the projection of L. In the next sentence the total L and is projection is mixed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Do you know if there is a classical way to argue this? Since when they performed the experiment, they did not know about the quantization of spin so how did they realize that the magnetic moment was proportional to the spin of the 47th electron without having quantum mechanics?